# nested quotes in haml

Tags: html, knockout.js, haml, rich-internet-application

I'm trying to convert my knockoutJs html code to HAML, trying to achieve something after compilation like:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': someValue }">...</div>
```

So I try:

```
%div{data:{bind:"attr: { 'data-something': someValue }"}}
```

But using haml_assets 0.1.0 I get:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { "data-something': someValue }'>...</div>
```

So my last resort was go back to:

```
== <div data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': someValue }">...</div>
```

Is this a bug in HAML, and/or is there a neater way to achive this?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the single quotes in your second example with a \. Total shot in the dark, I know nothing about haml.

Comment: Adding single quotes doesn't seem to help. Still produces the same result. I suspect the HAML processing to have a bug: it seems to detect somehow there was nesting (since it produces single quotes), but applies the quotes wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue on haml_assets 0.1.0. A ticket was created for this: https://github.com/infbio/haml_assets/issues/10

There is also a better workaround for it until it is fixed:

```
%div{data:{bind:'attr: { "data-something": someValue }'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%div(data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': someValue }")
```

When I did this in a RoR app that uses HAML I get this rendered:

```
<div data-bind="attr: { 'data-something': someValue }"></div>
```

Comment: I still got the same results, so I'm thinking that there is somthing wrong with the haml_assets gen I'm using. (It is about haml files in the asset pipeline.)